# Android recyclerview items overlap screen

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

In my android app I have a recyclerview inside my main activity.
These recyclerview is supposed to display documents to the user.

My problem is that the items overlap the right part of the screen. I don't know why it happens. I have worked with `CardView`s before but I can't seem to solve this.

Here is a screenshot of my problem:

[image]

As you can see, the right side of the `CardView`s overlaps the screen.

Here is the main activity layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/top_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorBackground"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="384dp"
        android:layout_height="567dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <com.silverfix.dgdeditor.utils.views.EmptyViewRecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/documents_rv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            tools:listitem="@layout/document_list_item" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/empty_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/empty_view"
            android:scaleX="0.5"
            android:scaleY="0.5" />
        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@drawable/menu_background"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:padding="10dp"
            app:menu="@menu/nav_drawer_menu"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
            app:itemTextAppearance="@style/NavDrawerTextStyle" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And here is the document_list_item code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/dg_card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/dg_card_view_height"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:foreground="?android:selectableItemBackground"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="3dp"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="5dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@drawable/nav_item_divider" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/document_card_name_tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/card_side_padding"
            android:text="Document: "
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/document_card_date_tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/document_card_name_tv"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/card_side_padding"
            android:text="Date"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Btw, a CardView is a regular FrameLayout that adds material properties (rounded corners and shadows/elevation) to it, so it shouldn't have anything to do with the problem at hand. I suggest you add background colors to each view group to see which one is not doing things as they should. I suspect you're missing a constraint.